# Lambda architecture on AWS: choose database for batch layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, bigdata, batch-processing, lambda-architecture

We're building Lambda architecture on AWS stack. A lack of devops knowledge forces us to prefer AWS managed solution over custom deployments.

Our workflow:

```
[Batch layer] 
Kinesys Firehouse -> S3 -Glue-> EMR (Spark) -Glue-> S3 views -----+                                                   
                                                                  |===> Serving layer (ECS) => Users                                                
Kinesys -> EMR (Spark Streaming) -> DynamoDB/ElasticCache views --+
[Speed layer]
```

We have already using 3 datastores: ElasticCache, DynamoDB and S3 (queried with Athena). Bach layer produce from 500,000 up to 6,000,000 row each hour. **Only last hour** results should be queried by serving layer with low latency random reads.

Neither of our databases fits batch-insert & random-read requirements. DynamoDB not fit batch-insert - it's too expensive because of throughput required for batch inserts. Athena is MPP and moreover has limitation of 20 concurrent queries. ElasticCache is used by streaming layer, not sure if it's good idea to perform batch inserts there.

Should we introduce the fourth storage solution or stay with existing?

Considered options:

1. Persist batch output to DynamoDB and ElasticCache (part of data that is updated rarely and can be compressed/aggregated goes to DynamoDB; frequently updated data ~8GB/day goes to elasticCache).
2. Introduce another database (HBase on EMR over S3/ Amazon redshift?) as a solution
3. Use [S3 Select over parquet](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/amazon-s3-announces-new-features-for-s3-select/) to overcome Athena concurrent query limits. That will also reduce query latency. But *have S3 Select any concurrent query limits?* I can't find any related info.

The first option is bad because of batch insert to ElasticCache used by streaming. *Also does it follow Lambda architecture - keeping batch and speed layer views in the same data stores?*

*The second solution is bad because of the fourth database storage, isn't it?*

Answer (score 1):

In this case you might want to use something like HBase or Druid; not only can they handle batch inserts and very low latency random reads, they could even replace the DynamoDB/ElastiCache component from your solution, since you can write directly to them from the incoming stream (to a different table).

Druid is probably superior for this, but as per your requirements, you'll want HBase, as it is available on EMR with the Amazon Hadoop distribution, whereas Druid doesn't come in a managed offering.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Are you sure that HBase could be used instead of ElasticCache on streaming part? It's based on block storages, HDFS or S3. Means hundreds of small random reads/writes may not perform so well as with ElastichCache. What is a latency of inserting/retrieving one row to/from HBase?

Comment: HBase (and Amazon Redshift) sounds like an overhead for me, if it won't replace DynamoDB/ElasticCache.  Both will add deployment complexity, both can operate over petabytes of data - but everything  I need is low latency random reads over last hour batch output. History batch output shoudn't have low latency.

Comment: Could you describe the kinds of queries you expect to handle, and how frequently? Usually the lambda architecture is used where you want the ability to query historic and near-realtime data through the same tools, where you are OK with some latency in general and OK with some inaccuracies in the most recent (speed layer) data. Does this also describe your case?

Comment: Our case is little bit different. Some computations are calculated only on Batch layer. That's because some computations are too complex for speed layer and not so frequent (i.e. once per hour or once per day).  For example, you have 20,000 users, and want to re-calculate some statistic for each user each hour. Once per hour means batch. But in the same moment, user can query related stats at any moment by `userId` with low latency.

Comment: if some calculation are performed only on batch layer, and we gonna query them in speed layer fashion - maybe it's right to store batch layer projections with speed layer projections? Maybe separate ElasticCache instances to isolate load...

Comment: In that case, you're probably on the right track with S3 Select or maybe Redshift Spectrum? HBase is still an option in combination with your existing DynamoDB/ElastiCache setup, although it's more involved since it's not SQL. Have you asked AWS Support about the S3 Select query concurrency? They should be able to redirect your question to the service team.

Comment: I was disappointed by latecy of S3 Select. It takes 4-5 seconds to choose one row from 10,000 by unique id.  I saved 10,000 rows to S3 in parquet format. Each row had 7 columns (2 Strings, 2 Longs, 3 Doubles). For some reason even if row is at the beginning of the file S3 select scans all file (even with `limit 1` at the end of the query)

Comment: What latency HBase will have? We are using S3 block storage, so HBase may also perform not so well. Main question now is - what is bad in storing Batch and Speed layer  views inside DynamoDB/ElasticCache. Maybe create separate instances of ElasticCache. Instead of increasing complexity of the system by introducing HBase

Comment: Storing your batch data in ElastiCache is going to be very expensive compared to S3, and as you mentioned, batch loading data to DynamoDB is not very flexible due since you have to adjust your write throughput up and down.

Comment: As for specific HBase latency, I'm afraid you'll have to experiment, as I can't give you a clear answer. But as far as I could understand, you did not have a requirement for very low latency reads from the batch data, only the speed layer data (which you already have in a fast cache)